# Fundamental group of a compact manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fundamental-group, smooth-manifolds

Why is the fundamental group of a compact manifold finitely presented?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Every compact manifold has the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex, and a finite CW-complex has finitely presented fundamental group by van Kampen's theorem.